generate model/ckpt file from YOLO format labeled text file?
I am trying to create my own ckpt file from scratch using annotation tool, where I start by annotating two images classified with 2 different classes and their width and height and position information as such:
<object-class> <x_center> <y_center> <width> <height>

now given that .txt YOLO format labeled text file I want to generate a model/checkpoint file to be used for image classification in another program.
How to do that?
